# Can't draw image on android phone

Tags: java, android, libgdx, draw, spritebatch

I have problem about drawing an image on phone.
On computer it draws correctly, but, on phone it replace itself with blackscreen.

It has been drawn with SpriteBatch:

```
batch.draw(peaks, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
```

and the image is [image] in .png format with resolution 1920 x 6000, size 89,1 kB

Comment: Don't use textures bigger than 2048 in either dimension.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, this is my case, now it is working!